# Typeahead in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Has anyone implemented Typeahead in visualforce? If so, were you able to apply any styles to it based on the styleClass attribute? I've been trying to get it to style something like a "mailing city" field in VF page but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?

```
<apex:page >
<style>

.defaultTextBox {
padding: 0;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
left: 0;
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
background-color: white;
font-size: 16px;
    }


</style>

    <c:Typeahead object="Account" placeholder="type something here..." primaryField="Name"
                 searchScope="Name" minSearchLength="3" styleclass="defaultTextBox" />   


 </apex:page>
```

I'm trying to use the Visualforce typeahead component. Here's the screenshot of where I'm struggling, [image]. I don't need such a big text box. How do I reduce the size, remove the bordering etc...that's where I'm struggling with.

Comment: It is always recommended to search before asking questions. If you find no results that match what your are asking then please ensure your question is specific and not so general.

Comment: @Eric, I have pasted a screenshot of what I'm needing help with. The defaultTextBox style that I've provided is not overriding the styles that the Typeahead component provides

Comment: How would you have expected anyone to understand that was what you were asking when you posted the original question???

Comment: update your css to style it properly, maybe add a width?

Comment: ok, Well I thought I did when I had the statement " I've been trying to get it to style something like a "mailing city" field in VF page but it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?" in my original question. Did you see that I have a style for defaultTextBox and it would NOT apply to this component. That's the problem really.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific with your selectors...

User inspector to find the ID

Changing it to this works:

```
#searchBox.defaultTextBox {
padding: 0;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
left: 0;
outline: none;
border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
background-color: white;
font-size: 16px;
width: 20%;
    }
```

The subject of CSS Specificity may be a good one to brush up on....

A starting point / example article

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Also, from the typeahead examples this works nicely. Modify slowly to get what you want and if you break something revert back and then read and understand why what you did broke it.:

```
<!-- Form that demonstrates use of the Force.com Typeahead component -->
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" title="Typeahead Test Page">

    <style>
        .sample-form { 
            margin: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            font-size: 16px; 
        }
        .sample-form h3 { 
            margin:8px 0; 
            display:block; 
        }
        .sample-form button { 
            margin: 18px 0; 
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="sample-form">

        <h3>Contact Name:</h3>
        <c:Typeahead /> 

        <button onclick="alert( 'You selected ' + document.getElementById('searchBox').getAttribute('data-id') );">Submit</button>

        <h3>Account Name:</h3>
        <c:Typeahead searchBoxId="acctSearchBox" object="Account" primaryField="Name" secondaryField="BillingCity" 
                searchScope="NAME" placeholder="Type something..." minSearchLength="3" 
                destinationForSelectedId="accountId" destinationForSelectedValue="accountName" stealFocus="false" />  

        <input type="hidden" name="accountId" id="accountId" />     
        <input type="hidden" name="accountName" id="accountName" />     

        <button onclick="alert( 'The hidden Id field contains ' + document.getElementById('accountId').value + '\nThe hidden Name field contains ' + document.getElementById('accountName').value );">Submit</button>

    </div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: do you know where could I find the "default" salesforce style properties - let's say for the mailing city field on the Account object?

Comment: Quickest way it to use browser dev tool and inspect the element to see what styling was applied.